# Why is POSIXct converted to numeric when converting list to vector

Tags: r, posixct

I have a list `redDressTweets` of `status`es. `status` is a class with a field `created`. I am trying to form a list of times in which tweets were posted. Here is how I'm trying to do it

```
times <- unlist(lapply(redDressTweets, function(tweet) {tweet$created }))
```

The output is a vector of numbers:

```
[1] 1478044029 1477954062 1477909847 1477887746 1477832560 1477640940 1477640939
[8] 1477628031 1477540826
```

But the class of `redDressTweets[[1]]$created` is `"POSIXct" "POSIXt"`.

Why is this happening and how do I stop it from converting POSIXct to numeric?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can reproduce more easily like this:

```
x <- list(as.POSIXct("2016-11-02"), as.POSIXct("2016-11-03"))
unlist(x)
#[1] 1478041200 1478127600
```

`unlist` combines the values inside the list. The internal representation of `POSIXct` variables are numeric values. They only are a `POSIXct` variable due to attributes, most importantly the `class` attribute. A list can hold all kinds of objects. The documentation says:

> Where possible the list elements are coerced to a common mode during
>   the unlisting, and so the result often ends up as a character vector.
>   Vectors will be coerced to the highest type of the components in the
>   hierarchy NULL < raw < logical < integer < double < complex <
>   character < list < expression: pairlists are treated as lists.

Note that it says "common mode", not common class. Since a class could be anything and could enforce any kind of underlying structure (e.g., it might not even be possible to combine two objects of the same class in a meaningful way), `unlist` just strips all attributes (except for a `list` where all elements are factors). It would be possible to handle `POSIXct` values like `factor` values, but that's not the case (and might have performance implications).

You can't avoid this, but fix it easily:

```
y <- unlist(x)
attributes(y) <- attributes(x[[1]])
y
#[1] "2016-11-02 CET" "2016-11-03 CET"
```

Obviously this assumes that all list elements have the same timezone attribute.

Comment: unless it's a named list. In this case you have to add poix-attribute, instead of just setting it:
  attributes(y) <- c(attributes(y), attributes(x[[1]]))